# ASP.net paypal form within server form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, paypal

If I put my Paypal button on my ASP.net website, it doesn't work because the whole page is wrapped in a `<form runat="server"></form>` tag.

What's the best way to integrate:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    ....
</form>
```

Onto my ASP.net page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [PayPal NVP API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview).  Gives you much more flexibility than the pre-made buttons as well.